# R: Unstack a table to reduce the dimensional

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
x1 <- read.table(header=T, text="
Batch   Parameter   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
Batch1  Parameter1  a   b   c   d   e
Batch1  Parameter2  f   h   i   j   k
Batch1  Parameter3  l   m   n   o   p
             ")
```

I would like to reformat (unstack?) in order to get this output:

```
a <- c("Batch", "Parameter1 V1",    "Parameter1 V2",    "Parameter1 V3",     
"Parameter1 V4",    "Parameter1 V5",    "Parameter2 V1",    "Parameter2 V2",     
"Parameter2 V3",    "Parameter2 V4",    "Parameter2 V5")
b <- c("Batch1","a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "h", "i", "j", "k")

x2 <- rbind(a,b)
```

I have tried to use unstack():

```
x3 <- unstack(x1, x1$Batch+x1$Parameter~V1:V5)
```

But this does not produce the required output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

W.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. "What happened to parameter3?" - I got lazy! In terms of doing it manually, the actual dataset is very large so that might not be a runner.

Comment: NM, now that you've edited it's much clearer what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
x1 %>% 
 gather("V","value",V1:V5) %>% 
 mutate(Parameter=paste0(Parameter,".",V)) %>% 
 select(-V) %>% 
 spread(Parameter,value)
```

Since you want to end up with one row of all combinations of parameters and V's, you start by creating one longdata format of all of these - and from there it's easy to `spread` it to the wide format.

```
   Batch Parameter1.V1 Parameter1.V2 Parameter1.V3 Parameter1.V4 Parameter1.V5 Parameter2.V1
1 Batch1             a             b             c             d             e             f
  Parameter2.V2 Parameter2.V3 Parameter2.V4 Parameter2.V5 Parameter3.V1 Parameter3.V2 Parameter3.V3
1             h             i             j             k             l             m             n
  Parameter3.V4 Parameter3.V5
1             o             p
```

Comment: This is excellent. Thank you so much for your help - it would have taken me an age to come up with that.